# How do I say "convince (someone) that (something)"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Convince -> 说服

How do I phrase a sentence, such as:

> I should convince her that it is not her fault.

Does this work (sounds odd): 我应该说服她，这不是她的错。

Or is there a more understandable / grammatically correct way of phrasing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convince:

- 1. **to make** (someone) **believe** = "**使**.....**相信**"

Example: **使**她**相信** (**make** her **believe**) 這不是她的錯 (that it is not her fault)

- 2. **to make** (someone) **+(verb)** = "**說服**" **+(verb)**

Example:  **說服**( convince)她**相信** (her **to believe**) 這不是她的錯 (that it is not her fault)

*相信 in this sentence is a verb that can be replaced with other verb, for example: "deny"

> *I should convince her that it is not her fault.*

base on the context of in this sentence, you are not convincing her to act, but convincing her to believe, so "使她相信這不是她的錯" is the  appropriate phrasing.